# jquery cycle 2 pager doubles items

Tags: jquery-cycle2

There is a similar question on here, but the solution doesn't work, and I can't comment on it, so I need to post a new question.

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
    data-cycle-caption-plugin=caption2
    data-cycle-pager="#cycle-pager"
    data-cycle-overlay-fx-sel=">div"
    >
  <div class="cycle-overlay"></div>
    <img src="/sites/default/files/images/banner_imag_1.jpg" title="Collaboratively administrate turnkey channels whereas virtual e-tailers." alt='Seamlessly empower fully researched growth strategies and interoperable internal or "organic" sources.' />
    <img src="/sites/default/files/images/blue-sky-basin-vail_0.png" title="What if world-leading organizations teamed-up to develop and scale technology and business solutions to global poverty?" alt="Efficiently unleash cross-media information without cross-media value." />
</div>
<div id="cycle-pager"></div>
```

Instead of two pager items, I'm getting four. Any insight would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: +1. I'm having the same problem. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: Oh, derp. I accidentally set Codekit to prepend the cycle plugin to itself, and then to my app-min.js file. So the JS was firing twice.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happened because you have inserted library for pagination. All you need is **delete the line**:

```
<script src="js/cycle/jquery.cycle2.pager.js"></script>
```